# Check if either one or two of any texboxes in vb.net has changed

Tags: vb.net

Is it possible to check if one or two of textboxes has changed their values?

I have updated my code based from one of the asnwers and i think i'm missing something. The query works only on the first run, if id and time were changed. If id was changed alone or both or just the time, it does not insert.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    idchanged = True
    flagam = True
    flagpm = True
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox2.TextChanged
    timechanged = True
    flagam = True
    flagpm = True
End Sub
```

MAIN

```
        Select Case True
            Case idchanged And timechanged
                Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand("select count(*) from attendance where date_format(pmin,'%m %d %Y') = date_format(now(),'%m %d %Y') and empid = '" & TextBox1.Text & "';", conn)
                Dim i As Integer = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
                cmd = Nothing
                If i = 0 AndAlso flagam = True AndAlso flagpm = True Then
                    str_insertAttendance = "insert ignore into attendance (empid, d, amin) values (@id, @date, @amIn)"
                    sqlCommand.CommandText = str_insertAttendance
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text))
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", time)
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@amIn", time)
                    sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    flagam = False
                ElseIf i = 0 AndAlso flagam = False AndAlso flagpm = True Then
                    str_insertAttendance = "update attendance set amout=@amout where empid=@id"
                    sqlCommand.CommandText = str_insertAttendance
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text))
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@amout", time)
                    sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    flagpm = False
                ElseIf i = 0 AndAlso flagam = False AndAlso flagpm = False Then
                    str_insertAttendance = "update attendance set pmin=@pmin where empid=@id"
                    sqlCommand.CommandText = str_insertAttendance
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text))
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pmin", time)
                    sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
                ElseIf i = 1 AndAlso flagam = False AndAlso flagpm = False Then
                    str_insertAttendance = "update attendance set pmout=@pmout where empid=@id"
                    sqlCommand.CommandText = str_insertAttendance
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text))
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pmout", time)
                    sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
                End If
                idchanged = False
                timechanged = False
            Case Not timechanged And idchanged
                Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand("select count(*) from attendance where date_format(pmin,'%m %d %Y') = date_format(now(),'%m %d %Y') and empid = '" & TextBox1.Text & "';", conn)
                Dim i As Integer = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
                cmd = Nothing
                If i = 0 AndAlso flagam = True AndAlso flagpm = True Then
                    str_insertAttendance = "insert ignore into attendance (empid, d, amin) values (@id, @date, @amIn)"
                    sqlCommand.CommandText = str_insertAttendance
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text))
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", time)
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@amIn", time)
                    sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    flagam = False
                ElseIf i = 0 AndAlso flagam = False AndAlso flagpm = True Then
                    str_insertAttendance = "update attendance set amout=@amout where empid=@id"
                    sqlCommand.CommandText = str_insertAttendance
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text))
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@amout", time)
                    sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    flagpm = False
                ElseIf i = 0 AndAlso flagam = False AndAlso flagpm = False Then
                    str_insertAttendance = "update attendance set pmin=@pmin where empid=@id"
                    sqlCommand.CommandText = str_insertAttendance
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text))
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pmin", time)
                    sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
                ElseIf i = 1 AndAlso flagam = False AndAlso flagpm = False Then
                    str_insertAttendance = "update attendance set pmout=@pmout where empid=@id"
                    sqlCommand.CommandText = str_insertAttendance
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text))
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pmout", time)
                    sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
                End If
                idchanged = False
            Case Not idchanged And timechanged
                Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand("select count(*) from attendance where date_format(pmin,'%m %d %Y') = date_format(now(),'%m %d %Y') and empid = '" & TextBox1.Text & "';", conn)
                Dim i As Integer = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
                cmd = Nothing
                If i = 0 AndAlso flagam = True AndAlso flagpm = True Then
                    str_insertAttendance = "insert ignore into attendance (empid, d, amin) values (@id, @date, @amIn)"
                    sqlCommand.CommandText = str_insertAttendance
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text))
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", time)
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@amIn", time)
                    sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    flagam = False
                ElseIf i = 0 AndAlso flagam = False AndAlso flagpm = True Then
                    str_insertAttendance = "update attendance set amout=@amout where empid=@id"
                    sqlCommand.CommandText = str_insertAttendance
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text))
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@amout", time)
                    sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    flagpm = False
                ElseIf i = 0 AndAlso flagam = False AndAlso flagpm = False Then
                    str_insertAttendance = "update attendance set pmin=@pmin where empid=@id"
                    sqlCommand.CommandText = str_insertAttendance
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text))
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pmin", time)
                    sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
                ElseIf i = 1 AndAlso flagam = False AndAlso flagpm = False Then
                    str_insertAttendance = "update attendance set pmout=@pmout where empid=@id"
                    sqlCommand.CommandText = str_insertAttendance
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text))
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pmout", time)
                    sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
                End If
                timechanged = False
        End Select
```

Comment: so in both cases you can check only textboxa, because textboxa changes when both of them change..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are relying on events, you  could yourself running up against the problem of which evaluation code to run.

As soon as the user changes anything `TextBox1`, the `TextBox1.Changed` event will fire even if a single key is pressed. There is no way to tell if the user is going to change `TextBox2` and have the code wait until all the changes are done before evaluation commences.

However, if you want to wait until the user has finished making changes to either or both `TextBoxes`, and then have them click a button (lets call it `btnEvaluate`), you could use the appropriate `.Changed` event for each textbox to alter a boolean flag to true and then in the `btnEvaluate` click event, you can run code appropriate to which flags are true.

Like this - I think..

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    tb1Changed = True
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox2.TextChanged
    tb2Changed = True
End Sub

Private Sub btnEvaluate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnEvaluate.Click
    Select Case True
        Case tb1Changed And tb2Changed
            'do stuff 1st block of code
            tb1Changed = False
            tb2Changed = False
        Case not tb1Changed And tb2Changed
            'dostuff 2nd block of code
            tb2Changed = False
    End Select
End Sub
```

You can of course remove the code to set the flags to `False` if you need them to remain `True` and put it elsewhere

Comment: hi sir, this is what i was thinking, there's just too much code in it i guess. let me try sir.

Comment: Looking at your updated question - I would suggest that instead of using text boxes, use labels because text boxes can accidentally be changed by the user.

Comment: thank you sir for the suggestion. i have it covered in the properties and so far they're all non-editable. i am trying out your code sir

Comment: sir, how do you convert the code to
`case tb1changed and tb2changed or just tb2changed 'dostuff`

Comment: I've updated my answer for you. Now. If both text boxes have changed, the first block of code runs. Or if only the 2nd text box has changed, the 2nd block of code runs.

Comment: Always glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

You can have both text boxes subscribe to the same event like this:

```
Private Sub TextBoxAOrB_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles textboxa.TextChanged, textboxb.TextChanged
    Dim txtBoxSender As TextBox = sender

    If txtBoxSender.Equals(textboxa) Then
        'DO STUFF
    ElseIf txtBoxSender.Equals(textboxb) Then
        If textboxa.Text <> id Then
            'TEXTBOX A also changed
            ' DO STUFF
        End If
    Else
        'SOMETHING WRONG
    End If
End Sub
```

Since you can only check one value at a time, this will run when textboxa changes, and run again if textboxb changes after that, but not if textboxb changes on it's own (which seems to be what you say in the question)

Comment: hi, this only works as AND right or does it return true for this
`if (textbox1.text changed) OR (textbox1.text changed AND textbox2.text changed)`

Comment: hi sir, i have a problem `empID.Text <> id`, my `id` here is from a fingerprint log via biometrics. which is stored to the textbox. i am unsure if this will work, since the textbox changes as soon as a new fingerprint instance logs in. i think it will always return `False`

Comment: Then you could store an old/new value. So old_id and current_id, and detect changes that way. `If empID.Text <> old_id Then` All of these are specifics to your code. So without knowing those specifics this answer is probably as good as it will ever get